# SoapException: Host is not known, only when called from WebService

Tags: asp.net, web-services, azure

I have a web app running .NET 4.5 on the Azure platform. As part of the web app we send leads off to a 3rd party web service. The decision was made for the front end to interact with a local web service (.asmx) via a JS AJAX call which in turn calls the 3rd party web service.

This is all working fine locally but falls down with a 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Host is not known' exception when moved to Azure.

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: No such host is known

at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

I've tested connectivity between Azure and the 3rd party WebService and they can communicate fine.

The thing that has me baffled is that if I call the code that sends the 3rd party request from code fired upon post back of a regular .aspx page it works. I'm assuming that there must be something in the way that Azure handles .asmx requests opposed to regular page loads that I can't fathom out.

Can anyone shed any light on the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message was a bit of a red herring. Turns out the problem was that the external web service was throwing a 500. We solved that and the error disappeared.